# Parse query string in JavaScript WHERE in Query

Tags: javascript, parsing, parse-platform, back4app

I have a Parse Class that contains a `Description` field.
I want to search for all instances that have any word(s) in the the Description.

For example in the search from angular web app the user enters `"tourism hotels and hospitals"`
I can do split for what he entered like : `["tourism", "hotels", "and", "hospitals"]`.
Now I want to query Parse for all records from the class that it's Description field contains "ANY" of these words.

Any Idea?? Please other than composing `god knows how many` queries with `Parser.Query.or`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Matching description field against array?

```
['Tourism is a fantastic', 'opportunity', 'to sell hotel rooms', 'at good prices','and drink beer', 'with the rest of your hotels friends']
    .filter( entry => entry.match( new RegExp( (["tourism", "hotels", "and", "hospitals"]).join('|'), 'gi' ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use contained in , like this

```
var listOfWords= ["tourism", "hotels", "and", "hospitals"];
query.containedIn("Description", listOfWords);
```